# How can I search for registered domains, but not unregistered domains?

Tags: dns, whois

There are many many services available to "search for domain names", but every one I have found returns results for **unregistered** domains; whereas I would like to a wildcard search for **registered** domains.

The purpose of my quest is to identify typosquatting and fake domains, e.g. if my company is `example.com` then I would like to be able to find `exrample.com`, `exampl.e.com`, `example.ru` etc.

Is there such a service, without enumerating all possibilities and using DNS resolution directly?

TLDR where can I find a list of all registered domain names?

Comment: Is this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322962/how-can-i-list-all-dns-records) asking the same thing as you? Aren't you talking about [`whois`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS)?

Comment: @Jedi I think he wants a bulk list of similar names, which is hard to do quickly via whois.

Comment: @AstroDan In the absence free-to-download up-to-date domain lists, I'd say `whois` is the fastest way to do this. Step 1: Apply mangling to generate list of candidates and Step 2: Perform whois lookup for each domain.

Comment: TLDR: the list of all registered domain names in all TLDs do not exist. You can get for free the list of all gTLDs published domain names (so you will miss some registered but not published) but for ccTLD it will be extremely difficult, as many registries are against it, to get the list of all registered domain names. Since you do not specify the TLDs you are interested in...

Answer (score 2):

You can also search through http://www.namedroppers.com/. I had not personally used this before but a quick test showed that it does find adjacent domains fairly well. It looks like the online search is free but you have to pay to download the list.

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with http://www.namedroppers.com/ nor do I endorse their service.

Comment: This is neat, though it doesn't seem to find nearby domains, it simply finds all domains where the keyword is a substring.

Comment: @jedi You can break up the search a bit more then that see http://www.namedroppers.com/uses.html. But you are right it is limited, but it is easy and fast

Comment: This is a very good resource. This is basically exactly what Anonymous is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I have done similar analysis in the past by downloading WHOIS datasets, for instance from [here](https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whois-database-download.php).

The dataset has many useful fields including the domain name, the registrant information (name/address/ph). The dataset also spans multiple major TLDs like com,org,net,info,mobi,etc. Note that it is not free, but also not expensive from a product development standpoint.